# Multi-site application gateway path-based routing not sending traffic to Apache on VMs

Tags: azure, http-redirect, azure-application-gateway

In Azure Application Gateway (standard tier), I have a couple of multi-site listeners:

**listener-one-http (80 with hostname www.staging.example.com )**
The basic rule sends traffic to the following listener:

**listener-two-https (443 with hostname www.staging.example.com )**
This path-based rule sends traffic to VM-01 or VM-02 if path contains "mystore". Apache is configured on both these VMs for different sites.

Path-based rules are:

```
Name: www.staging.example.com-https-rule
Listener: listener-two-https
Backend pool: VM-01-Pool
Default HTTP settings: HTTPS-Backend

Name, Paths, Backend pool, HTTP setting
store, /mystore/*, VM-02-Pool, HTTPS-Backend
all, /*, VM-01-Pool, HTTPS-Backend
```

The basic rule is being enforced (http to https) but the path-based rule set appears to be ignored. In my browser, I enter http://www.staging.example.com and this results in https://www.staging.example.com (good) but then I get the following message (bad):

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Is there a way to trace what's happening between the application gateway and Apache without checking on the VMs?

Comment: It looks like the rules are correct but traffic is not being sent to the backend pool due to unhealthy instances, found under Application Gateway > Backend health in Azure. The error is "Cannot connect to server. Check whether any NSG/UDR/Firewall is blocking access to server. Check if application is running on correct port." How do I change this to probe on port 80 and not 443 in Azure?

Comment: Are you trying end to end SSL? What is your HTTP Settings config ? Are you using default probe config now? You can try to create custom probe where you need to add Trusted root cert if the backend is not a well known CA.

Comment: Yes, the SSL termination is working as expected but traffic is not being sent to the backend VMs due to health check failing. Where is the "Port (HTTP setting)" under "Backend health" defined?

Comment: Probes are associated to the HTTP Settings.

Comment: I think I worked out the problem. A rule in the app gateway seems to be overriding the listener/rules I have added. Either that or app gateway is not propagating the changes. I decided to test this by deleting the listener/rules but the traffic still ended up on the VM even though routing wasn't there. I verified this in the access logs for the app gateway in storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a /* rule, it breaks.

[Tutorial: Create an application gateway with path-based routing rules using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal)

> **Note**
>
> You do not need to add a custom /* path rule to handle default cases. This is automatically handled by the default backend pool.